# Firebase orderByChild not getting results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query my database to get all the dates which has `child number > 7`

```
this.extra = function() {
    refer = ref.child(slot);
    refer.orderByChild('number')
         .startAt('7')
         .once('value')
         .then(function (snapshot) {
             console.log(snapshot.key());
         });
}
```

But am getting null results, any idea why?

[image: A look at firebase database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `'7'` (with quotes) but have the value stored as `7` (without quotes). This means that you're comparing strings and numbers, which will not work.

Instead use this:

```
ref.child(slot)
   .orderByChild('number')
   .startAt(7)
   ...
```